# Soap web service to update screen returns error on login

Tags: acumatica

I have a web service that updates the ProjectTask screen in 2019 R2 - it used to work fine in an older version (pre-2018 R1), but now it gets an error on login (the last line of the code below), shown here:

```
            ProjectTasks.Screen projectTasksContext = new ProjectTasks.Screen();
            projectTasksContext.Url = "https://<url here>/Soap/PM302000.asmx";

            projectTasksContext.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

            ProjectTasks.LoginResult projectTasksLoginResult = projectTasksContext.Login("<user>", "<password>");
```

Here is the relevant error message, which doesn't mean anything to me:

[image]

Inner exception as follows:

?ex.InnerException
    {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232800
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}
    Message: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
    Source: "System"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32      size)\r\n   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionConte
xt.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)"
    TargetSite: {Int32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)}

Any ideas?  Is there a setting in 2019 R2 I need to look at that wasn't in previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS 1.2 is not required by Acumatica when connecting via HTTPS. The error message is not clear at all and it was a little bit puzzling to me as well the first time I ran into this problem. Newer versions of the .NET Framework (4.6+) automatically use TLS 1.2 but it is not the case with older versions.

- .NET 4.6 and above. You don’t need to do any additional work to support TLS 1.2, it’s supported by default.
- .NET 4.5. TLS 1.2 is supported, but it’s not a default protocol. You need to opt-in to use it. The following code will make TLS 1.2 default, make sure to execute it before making a connection to secured resource:
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
- .NET 4.0. TLS 1.2 is not supported, but if you have .NET 4.5 (or above) installed on the system then you still can opt in for TLS 1.2 even if your application framework doesn’t support it. The only problem is that SecurityProtocolType in .NET 4.0 doesn’t have an entry for TLS1.2, so we’d have to use a numerical representation of this enum value:
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
- .NET 3.5 or below. TLS 1.2 is not supported (*) and there is no workaround. Upgrade your application to more recent version of the framework.

Source: [Perficient Blog - TLS 1.2 and .NET Support: How to Avoid Connection Errors](https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/)

If for whatever reason you are *not* able to recompile your application, there is a [registry hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2) that you can use to force .NET to use TLS 1.2

Comment: I'm not seeing a solution here...  sorry - maybe I wasn't clear - I'm simply consuming an Acumatica soap web service  using a C# application.  I'm not determining what framework to use.  In any case, if I change the framework of my C# app to 4.6, I get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I understood that you are consuming a web service. The error occurs because a secure connection can’t be established. Have you tried forcing TLS 1.2 by make this call before you connect to Acumatica? ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 - this is part of the Acumatica application certification requirements as well

Comment: Haven't gotten to the web service certifications yet.  Mentioning the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol setting right at the outset here would have solved the issue immediately.  Thanks.